# Carnap's method of induction

Tags: logic, probability, carnap

Carnap provides a general understanding of symbolic induction, given as *c(h, e)=r*.

1. c = degree of confirmation
2. h = hypothesis
3. e = evidence
4. r = outcome

What exactly is meant by Carnap's 'degree of confirmation'? Is it an expectation given h and e, as a method of belief? If so, did he think of developing a ranking criteria towards his inductive method? Does this work for c?

Also, he mentions the 'm' function. However, I cannot seem to wrap around how this relates to the 'c' function.

Furthermore, are there modern advancements on Carnap’s inductive probability, still used in statistics, or programming?

Comment: See [Carnap: Inductive Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/carnap/index.html#InduLogi) with [Supplement](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/carnap/inductive-logic.html)

Comment: Having read both; Not much is mentioned on the m-function and its relation to the c-function.

Comment: Although, this article clarifies both functions [Carnap's System](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/20114867.pdf?casa_token=6Y7n_Vd0QscAAAAA:M1CGu-Z8meHDDQICz2gCPO5uWm0ELCRjkS0l6wj4Nn-ZWiGCf-b48C1zwvYexumtuiZKLqLUUghhtL0p8NIVOOFiCy9NXEIJUdevQuU848Mkrebxgu0)

Comment: If you're looking for a method to objectively find the best explanation for some phenomenon given some available (and possibly noisy) data, see [this approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1736327/21820). All other approaches that I have seen so far fail to achieve the same guarantees.

Answer (score 1):

The function 'm' Carnaps details as a 'measure functions', in a finite system L_N; This is any distribution of positive real numbers, whose sum is 1, among the state-description. Then we define m(j) for a sentence j as the sum of the m(state-descriptions) for those state-descriptions in which j holds.

By degree of confirmations, this ultimately is dependent on the tautology of the statement. Given that it follows probability axioms, like conditional expectation therefore:

c(h.e)/c(e)